# How to get changes to .hgignore honored in remote repo

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I recently pushed some changes to a Mercurial repo (the remote server) and realized my `.hgignore` was misconfigured, as certain files (binaries, etc.) were included in the commit/push which should have bee ignored.

So I tweaked my `.hgignore` and got it perfect, and then push that change. To my surprise, the remote server's web ui (RhodeCode) still shows the "bad" files as belonging to the repo. I would have expected them to be automagically culled out since they violate the `.hgignore`.

So it looks like I need to do some magic locally that makes my working copy honor the ignore changes, and then push those changes. Perhaps remove the files from tracking?

As a concrete example, in my repo root I have `myapp-meta.bin`. So in `.hgignore` I added an entry for `*.bin`. What exact commands would I need to do in order to remove `*.bin` from tracking (but not the file system!) and so they don't show up in the latest/head version on the remote repo?

Also, does `hg` have anything similar to Git's dry run (`git add . -n`)? Would be handy in the future to see what *would* be added to tracking before I actually go ahead and do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already added `myapp-meta.bin`, so it's tracked despite you added it later to `.hgignore`. If you delete it from the repo it won't be shown as a new file and will be ignored.

As for dry run, many commands (and `hg add` is among them) support `-n` or `--dry-run` option.

Comment: Thanks @Paul (+1) - how about something like `hg addremove`? I *really* don't want to delete it from the file system because its a PITA to generate (trust me). Would this command remove the file from tracking, somehow differently than what the `.hgignore` does? If so, can you provide an example of using it with my bin file?

Comment: Do you want the file to be in the repo, and in the same time have Mercurial ignore changes to that file? Or you just want to remove the file from the repo, but preserve it locally?

Comment: Use `hg forget` to make Mercurial stop tracking the file without removing it from the file system.